# lualatex and changing the font size of arabverse environment

Tags: luatex, arabic

I am using `arabluatex` package with `lualatex` system. Three questions please:

1. The text does not scale appropriately with the `arabverse` environment. This is the tex file:

```
\documentclass[article, 11pt, b6paper, landscape, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage[nopar]{quran}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

This is with normal font:

\begin{arabverse}
    \begin{linenumbers}
      \bayt{الشطر الأول}[]{الشطر الثانى}\\
    \end{linenumbers}
\end{arabverse}

This is by using \texttt{tiny} fontsize:

\begin{arabverse}\tiny
    \begin{linenumbers}
      \bayt{الشطر الأول}[]{الشطر الثانى}\\
    \end{linenumbers}
\end{arabverse}

\end{document}
```

This is an example of the output:

[image]

2. Isn't there a simpler command instead of `\bayt{}[]{}\\`; e.g., something like: `Text & Text\\`
3. Another general question please: why should I use `lualatex` system with `arabluatex` package instead of using pdflatex with arabtex? I am just writing in English and Arabic

EDIT:
I managed to produce a LISP function to convert from the text writing style of any Arabic Poem to \bayt style of the package:

```
(defun text-to-bayt ()
(interactive)

  ;;remove the in-between marks (.....) or (   ...   ) between the two parts of a bayt.
  (goto-char 1)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\(\\s-*\\.\\{2,\\}\\s-*\\)" nil t)
    (replace-match " === " t nil))

  ;;put a bay in the form \bayt{SADR}[]{AGEZ}
  (goto-char 1)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "^\\([^=]+\\) === \\([^=]+\\)$" nil t)
    (replace-match
     (concat
      "\\\\bayt{" (match-string 1) "}[]{" (match-string 2) "}\\\\\\\\" )t nil))

  ;; remove the carriage return that was at the end of each bayt which is now followed by "}" (easier to be removed here)
  (goto-char 1)
  (while (search-forward-regexp "
}" nil t)
    (replace-match "}" t nil))

  )
```

Comment: It’s best to ask one question at a time. But about your third, if you’re familiar with `arabtex` and satisfied with its output, there’s no reason why you can’t use it. If you want more choice of typefaces, then there’s `arabxetex` as well as `arabluatex`. `arabluatex` is newest and still rapidly developing, so you may find a bug now and then, but if you need `luatex` for other reasons, then `arabluatex` is for you.

Comment: Thanks so much; should I remove the first two question?

Comment: The reason for asking one question at a time seems to be mostly that it makes searching for a particular topic easier. But we don’t (yet) have so many questions on `arabluatex` that it’s hard to search through them, so you can probably leave this question in its present state. What we do have is the author of `arabluatex` among our users:  @RobertAlessi will be able to explain the workings of his verse environment.

Comment: I came across this one by chance as for some reason it does not show by just putting `arabluatex` in the search box.  @Thérèse is right to the point in her answer.  As for the `arabverse` environment, and the `\bayt` command, well, this would be way to long to explain here; to put it very shortly `arabluatex` is primarily designed to process `ASCII arabtex` code which had to be passed on to some `lua` functions very early. Besides, as the versions to come will also produce `TEI xml` compliant files, very tight encoding is required.

Comment: "I came across this one by chance as for some reason it does not show by just putting arabluatex in the search box." Wrong statement, sorry.

Comment: So you mean I cannot use smaller font size inside this `arabverse`? Thanks so much.

Comment: Of course you can: just do `\begin{arabverse}\small` before the actual lines: `\bayt{}{}`. By the way, `arabluatex` also includes an `arabluatex.el` file that you may want to copy to your `~/.emacs.d/auctex/auto` local directory. This will enable the appropriate hooks for `arabluatex` in AUCTeX.

Comment: Ok, but part (1) of my question (at the top of the page) says that when I do `\begin{arabverse}\small` the font is not scaled!

Comment: I edited the original post and added an image of the output

Comment: Inside `arabverse` environment you /must/ use `\bayt{}{}` which you did not in your above example.

Comment: No, I did; this was produced by `\bayt`

Comment: I updated the original post to add the tex file.

Comment: I see. What you got is what's expected, as your tiny Arabic has been stretched to `\baytwidth`. Please read to documentation sect. 5 on p. 27 for more details. BTW: also mind to put \\ after each bayt, like so: `\bayt{}{}\\\`

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and effort. Last thing, does `\bayt` have a replacement like: `&  \\` or this is what you meant above by "would take too long"

Comment: No replacement for `\bayt` I'm afraid.  At present I'm even working on a more complicated command for typesetting the muwashshaḥāt! You should try to load `arabluatex.el`: it helps a lot. Also, there is no need to type the square brackets if you don't have a tadwīr. Just do `\bayt{}{}` plus \\.

Comment: Thank you so much; this replies all of my questions in this thread. I will definitely try arabluatex.el right now. I really appreciate your great support. --Waleed

Comment: I tried arabluatex.el; very nice. BTW, why it does not load automatically when I do `\usepackage{arabluatex}` as other packages do. Why do I need to do something like: `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(load "arabluatex.el"))`

Comment: For an already written poetry without `\bayt{}{}`, do you have an emacs lisp function that converts all the written to `\bayt{}{}` style? It is very tedious to do it manually by copy and paste

Comment: You're welcome. `arabluatex.el` still has to be included in `auctex`. I will do that when I have time. As to the lisp function you mentioned, you could just record a macro (`Ctrl-x (` to start and `Ctrl-x )` to stop recording) on one line, then iterate it through all the lines (with `Ctrl-u` several times). See here how to do that: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros

Comment: I really appreciate your patience and support. I was tempted to produce a meaningful LISP function that can be customized later. I wrote it and here you go if you like to use you are more than welcome (I added at the end of the original post because of the size limitation of a comment)

Comment: I just noticed your script: many thanks, I will definitely use it.